# Kinvey: Object not saving due to error: Cannot map 'X', a non-existant property

Tags: ios, swift, kinvey

I'm part of the group moving from Parse and checking out Kinvey. However, I can't get objects to save. I get the error:

> error : Error Domain=KCSAppDataErrorDomain Code=60102 "Entity does not have property 'NumberOfPlayers' as specified in hostToKinveyPropertyMapping" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check the hostToKinveyPropertyMapping for typos and errors., NSLocalizedDescription=Entity does not have property 'NumberOfPlayers' as specified in hostToKinveyPropertyMapping, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Cannot map 'NumberOfPlayers', a non-existant property}

I have followed the guide on their website here:
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/datastore#create

My Code:

```
class Event: NSObject {
var objectId:String?
var Sport:Int?
var NumberOfPlayers:Int?
var SkillLevel:Int?
var Date:NSDate?
var Time:NSDate?
var Competitive:NSNumber?

override func hostToKinveyPropertyMapping() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]! {
    return [
        "objectId" : KCSEntityKeyId,
        "Sport" : "Sport",
        "NumberOfPlayers" : "NumberOfPlayers",
        "SkillLevel" : "SkillLevel",
        "Date" : "Date",
        "Time" : "Time",
        "Competitive" : "Competitive",
    ]
}
}
```

And the saving:

```
let event = Event()
    event.Sport = 0
    event.NumberOfPlayers = playerQuantity
    event.SkillLevel = skillLevel
    event.Date = date
    event.Time = time
    event.Competitive = competitive

    let collection = KCSCollection(fromString: "Event", ofClass: Event.self)
    let store = KCSAppdataStore(collection: collection, options: nil)

//        let store = KCSAppdataStore.storeWithOptions([
//            KCSStoreKeyCollectionName : "Event",
//            KCSStoreKeyCollectionTemplateClass : Event.self
//            ])

    store.saveObject(event, withCompletionBlock: { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil { print("error : \(error)"); return }
        print("saved objects")
        }, withProgressBlock: nil)
```

Neither way of creating the DataStore has worked. They both return the same error.

I have also checked that the `AppId` and `AppSecret` are both correct. I can  `sign up` Users and `login` ok, I just can't save data.

Any ideas?

Comment: FIXED: Properties cannot be of Int? Type. Instead they have to be NSNumbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any number types should be classified as NSNumbers instead of Ints